# Ruby on Rails: Two different "new" actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, crud

In my *transactions* controller I have action "topup" and "purchase". Both are doing similar thing as "new" action.

In my "view" controllers I have submit button, in both views these buttons should lead to "create" action.

How do I set it?

Comment: Please provide some example code for you controllers, your routes file, and your views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to use the same form in both places.

In the controller for each action, create a new transaction with whatever 
attributes it needs based on being topup or purchase.

```
def topup
  ...
  @transaction = Transaction.new
end

def purchase
  ...
  @transaction = Transaction.new
end
```

Then in the views

```
<%= form_for @transaction do |form| %>
... needed fields
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `form action url` by yourself. Just provide the `:url` parameter to the two forms.

Example:

```
<%= form_for :your_resource, url: create_path do |f| %>
    ...
<%= end %>
```

You have to add the `create_path` also in your `routes.rb` of course.

```
post 'create', as: create  # <= This is just an example for your routes!
```

The `form helpers` are described in detail in the [Docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html).